# html table into phpexcel

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

```
require_once 'data.php';
echo '<table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2" border="1">';
reset($mas);
$header = current($mas);
$header = array_merge(array('tankla'=>'tankla'), $header);
foreach ($header as $key=>$val) {
    echo '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';
foreach ($mas as $tankla=>$data) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.utf8_decode($tankla).'</td>';
    foreach ($data as $day=>$value) {
        echo '<td style="text-align: right;">'.$value.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

I need this thing to be inside phpexcel. Any advice on how to make this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [PHPEXCEL](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library

Example Usage:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

//foreach loop{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A', <your_column_val>);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B', <your_column_val>);

//}
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('your_file_name.xlsx');
```

Comment: i have no use of that, because i am too amateur for undersanding this

Comment: Either output buffer your table building code, save to a temp file, and use PHPExcel's html reader to load the PHPExcel object before saving it as Excel; or modify your loops to populate the PHPExcel worksheet object

Comment: whaaa?? :D believe it i am too newbie for this :D i have done one simple task that other may do in 5 minutes i have done it 7 hours already :D

Comment: Why can't you use the loop code I answered for your previous question as the basis for this?

Comment: edited the code little bit, basically i need to get array into xml table with this html coding

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = 1;
$column = 'A';
foreach ($header as $key=>$val) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(
        $column . $row,
        $key
    );
    $column++;
}
$row++;
foreach ($mas as $tankla=>$data) {
    $column = 'A';
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(
        $column . $row,
        utf8_decode($tankla)
    );
    foreach ($data as $day=>$value) {
        $column++;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(
            $column . $row,
            $value
        );
    }
    $row++;
}
```

Comment: almost right output, expect that ÖÄÜÕ included names dont appear , or only have the first letter,
plus A1 must be A2 and A2 must be A3 and so on

Comment: Ensure that __all__ of your text values are UTF-8, and modify the $row value as necessary

Comment: how can i modify rows and so on?

Comment: $row is the Excel row number (e.g. 1); $column is the Excel column letter (e.g. 'A'). The Cell address is the column concatenated with the row (e.g. 'A1'). If you want to start at row 2, then change $row=1; to $row=2; in the first line of my code above